# Chamar interface gráfica no java

Tags: java, interface

Minha duvida é simples, acredito eu. Preciso chamar essa interface `CadastroGUI d = new CadastroGUI()`; que já tenho pronta, mas quero que os campos já aparecam preenchidos, afinal, é um comando de consulta por CPF onde quero como retorno as informações do cliente.

**O Código**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                String cpf = txtCPF.getText();

                DaoCadastro c = new DaoCadastro();
                ArrayList <Cadastro> co = new ArrayList <Cadastro>();

                CadastroGUI d = new CadastroGUI();
                d.setVisible(true);

                co = c.listaAlterar(cpf);
                int a=0;

                for (a=0; a<co.size();a++)

                {
                    txtNome.setText (co.get(a).Nome);
                    txtCPF.setText (co.get(a).CPF);
                    txtEndereco.setText(co.get(a).Endereco);
                    txtSexo.setText(co.get(a).Sexo);
                    txtDataNasc.setText (co.get(a).Datanasc);



            }
```

Comment: Você chama CadastroGui de outra tela e quer que ela venha preenchida com as informações da tela anterior?

Comment: Eu tenho o modelo CadastroGui pronto, então quero fazer uma consulta através do CPF em outra interface, chamar a CadastroGui quando preencher o CPF e apertar um jbutton `procurar`  e receber as informações já `setadas` na CadastroGui que vai ser chamada

Comment: Quando eu coloco esse  **CadastroGUI d = new CadastroGUI();
                d.setVisible(true);** ela ta vindo, mas não esta preenchida. Quero que venha preenchida com as informações que estão ligadas ao CPF que vou procurar.

Comment: Essas informações veem da tela que chama CadastroGUI ou você já traz direto do banco?

Comment: cuidado ao usar a palavra interface dessa forma, em java ela tem outro significado. Como vc envia as informações para o CadastroGUI? ela é um JFrame?

Comment: O que o @Skywalker disse é verdade. Sugiro que edite o titulo da pergunta para "interface grafica" já que estamos falando de GUI's.

Comment: Cada vez vou aprendendo mais com vocês, porque sou iniciante em programação kk. Eu trago do banco @DiegoFelipe.

Comment: É JFrame sim @Skywalker, as informações preenchidas em JTextFields.

Comment: envie as informações que você deseja exibir no CadastroGUI por um construtor. Faça um construtor no CadastroGUI.

Answer (score 4):

Crie um outro construtor em CadastroGUI com parâmetro para o seu arraylist:

```
    CadastroGUI(ArrayList<Cadastro> co)
    {
        CadastroGUI();
        //aqui você faz o preenchimento dos campos.
        int a=0;
        for (a=0; a < co.size(); a++)
        {
            txtNome.setText (co.get(a).Nome);
            txtCPF.setText (co.get(a).CPF);
            txtEndereco.setText(co.get(a).Endereco);
            txtSexo.setText(co.get(a).Sexo);
            txtDataNasc.setText (co.get(a).Datanasc);
        }
    }
```

E no seu evento você simplesmente chama ele passando o arraylist por parâmetro:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
        String cpf = txtCPF.getText();
        DaoCadastro c = new DaoCadastro();
        ArrayList <Cadastro> co = new ArrayList <Cadastro>();
        co = c.listaAlterar(cpf);
        CadastroGUI d = new CadastroGUI(co);
        d.setVisible(true);
    }
```